# How do I safely sync data between two EC2 instances on the same ELB?

Tags: rsync, amazon-ec2, load-balancer

I have two ec2 instances on a load balancer, I would want to be able to make one the source and the other a mirror. Where the source is the instance that is always updated, and the mirror updates itself from the source.

I would use rsync in this case, my only concern is what happens when the source for some reason goes out of date? (In this case the mirror is ahead of source). How do I get notified, and or how can it rectify itself?

Thanks.

Comment: How can the source be out of date when it is the source of truth? What kind of data do you sync? Static pages, or uploaded content? Perhaps use something like Amazon EFS instead?

Comment: All website files (static pages, uploaded content)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Amazon EBS. This will give you persistent block storage and high availability, which sounds like your goal. AWS EBS is easy to manage with the console and you can [copy volumes](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/managing-ebs-volumes-in-aws-cloud) easily.

If you want to keep the rsync option, then I would put the rsync command into a script, pipe the output into a file and email it to myself.  Or you could monitor the logs for appropriate errors via a cron job and add a notification for those errors into the cron script.  These options are more resource intensive than using AWS services.

In regards to the "rectify" part of the question; I am not sure how the primary system would ever be out of date. I'm sure you have regular backups scheduled and would take a snapshot before any major changes, so that can be used to restore the system to the last known operational state.